Validator returns "Attribute media not allowed on element source at this point"
My issue can be summarized with the following screenshot:

Am I not understanding what this error means?
Here's the full code:
    <video class="entry-video" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted playsinline loop>
      <source type="video/mp4" media="(orientation: portrait)" src="http://localhost/.../file.mp4">
      <source type="video/mp4" media="(orientation: landscape)" src="http://localhost/.../file.mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>↩


Using Firefox, but does this make any difference in the context of validating code with https://validator.w3.org/ ?
Just tested validating the same code in Chrome and it returns the same error.
